# key escrow vs secure storage(software/TPM/HSM)

Tags: encryption, storage, hsm

From the definition of key escrow (a method to store important cryptographic keys providing **data-at-rest** protection), it sounds very similar to that of secure storage which could be basically software-based or hardware-based (TPM/HSM).
But, I could not figure out any differences or similarities between these two on the internet.

Are key-escrow and secure storage the one and the same or not? Or is it just a marketing terminology?

Comment: Where did you get the definition of key escrow from?

Comment: https://jumpcloud.com/blog/key-escrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An escrow isn't a method, its more of an agreement. merriam webster defines the term escrow as

> a deed, a bond, money, or a piece of property held in trust by a third party to be turned over to the grantee only upon fulfillment of a condition

So in the case of [key escrows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_escrow), you simply entrust your cryptographic keys to the key escrow provider to turn over to someone when a specific condition is fulfilled. In the case of a commercial key escrow, the condition is just that they confirm that the entity asking for the keys is authorized to access them. In case of a law enforcement key escrow, the condition would be that the LEOs have a valid warrant. Note that a key escrow by itself does not provide any protection. Protecting the keys is up to the key escrow provider.

An HSM on the other hand is a physical device that is designed to protect data (usually cryptographic keys). So, although a key escrow provider *might* be using an HSM to store escrowed keys, the two are fundamentally different things.